# Using React and Canvas to create a dynamic editor

Tags: reactjs, next.js, html5-canvas, fabricjs

I'm working on an editor where a user adds, updates, and removes elements from a Canvas.  I'm using FabricJS to actually do the drawing, but I don't think this matters.

Configuration is stored in POJOs in a redux store, and this is loaded into the canvas.  As the user updates the canvas, either through the Fabric controls or through custom controls in React, these updates are emitted as events from Fabric and are propagated into my redux store.

The issue I'm having is finding a good way to handle state.  The single biggest issue I'm dealing with is that each state update triggers a re-render which causes my entire editor canvas to flash as the canvas is torn down and re-rendered.

I have already implemented [Adam's fantastic post on "persistent layouts" in NextJS](https://adamwathan.me/2019/10/17/persistent-layout-patterns-in-nextjs/).  This actually solved another issue I had with flashes caused by page routing.  However, I don't think I'm able to apply the same pattern to this.

I have tried the following:

- `memo` - This doesn't work well for canvas as it still shows the flash, even if props don't change
- `useRef` - Remove any reactive state that could cause a re-render from my component (and parents).  However, I'm not sure how to then propagate state changes to and from the canvas.
- In addition to the above, try using a global event bus for communication.  This seems very annoying to work with and debug, so I want to ask before I implement this.

Has anybody solved a problem like this before?  Specifically, how to get around re-rendering a Canvas while still enabling it to have some access to Redux state.

I'd be happy to provide a sample repo of the issue if this is unclear.

Comment: I would store canvas state in ref instead of a state

Comment: I did mention that's something that I've tried, although I could have been clearer.  I'm guessing that whatever solution I come up with to propagate state will be reliant on this though.

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite understand the issue here, but I'm not familiar with `FabricJS`